# Array as map key

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, maps, operator-overloading

I'm trying to use an array as map key. I got it working but as soon as I try to integrate it in a class I'm getting the following compiler error:

> In instantiation of ‘T& Matrix::operator[](std::array) [with T = double]’:
>   35:12:   required from here
>   20:24: error: no match for call to ‘(std::map, double, std::less >, std::allocator, double> > >) (const std::array&)’
>        return matrix(index);

This is what my code looks like:

```
#include <map>

template <typename T>
struct Matrix{
    std::map<std::array<int,2>,T> matrix;
    int rows;
    int columns;

    Matrix()
    : rows(0),
      columns(0)
    {  }

    Matrix(int rows,int columns)
    :  rows(rows),
    columns(columns)
    { }

    T& operator[](const std::array<int,2> index){
    return matrix(index);
}

    T& operator[](const std::array<int,2>& index) const{
    return matrix(index);
}

};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Matrix<double> M(10,10);
    double a = 10;
    M[{10,11}] = a;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're also calling `operator() (std::array<int ,2>)` on your map, instead of `at(std::array<int, 2>)` (in your `operator[]` functions).

Comment: why do you want to use an `array` and not a `tuple`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In these operators

```
T& operator[](const std::array<int,2> index){
return matrix(index);
}

T& operator[](const std::array<int,2>& index) const{
return matrix(index);
}
```

you are trying to call a non-existent operator function of the class template std::map

```
matrix(index)
```

It is evident you mean in the first subscript operator

```
matrix[index]

T& operator[](const std::array<int,2> &index){
return matrix[index];
}
```

and in the second subscript operator the member function at.

```
const T& operator[](const std::array<int,2>& index) const{
return matrix.at(index);
}
```

Also the second operator should be declared with the returned type qualified with the qualifier const that is it should return a constant reference because the member function is in turn a constant function.

Comment: @ThomasSablik: `at` should be used instead of `operator[]` there.

Comment: @ThomasSablik Oh, I forgot that the subscript operator inserts data if it is absent.:)

Comment: Thanks this helped a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Like the error message says, the problem is here:

```
    return matrix(index);
```

It should be:

```
    return matrix[index];
```

Notice the `[]` operator.

Also `matrix[index]` can't be called in a `const` context since in C++ `map::operator[]` creates missing elements, and so is a potentially mutating operation. I would re-think your design, otherwise there will be discrepancy between how your non-const `[]` and `const []` behave with regard to missing keys.

Note: you should also `#include <array>`.

---

P.S. The compare operator for `std::array` [is provided](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/operator_cmp).

Answer (score 1):

You have some problems in your code:

- missing include for `array` (works with gcc but not with clang)
- usage of missing call operator
- usage of copies instead of const references

```
#include <array> // Added include
#include <map>

template <typename T>
struct Matrix{
    std::map<std::array<int,2>,T> matrix;
    int rows;
    int columns;

    Matrix()
    : rows(0),
      columns(0)
    {  }

    Matrix(int rows,int columns)
    :  rows(rows),
    columns(columns)
    { }

    T& operator[](const std::array<int,2> &index){
        return matrix[index]; // replace call operator
    }

    const T& operator[](const std::array<int,2> &index) const{ //return const reference
        return matrix.at(index); // replace call operator
    }

};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Matrix<double> M(10,10);
    double a = 10;
    M[{10,11}] = a;


    return 0;
}
```